# How to fadeout image, then make it appear on another position in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my image is at some div, and it's z-index is the highest

When i click on something, I want it to fade out, and fade in on another, specified position. Below the image of another class : ) It's an "aaa" class.

I was doing it like that:

```
          $('img.classy').fadeOut();
          $('img.classy').css('top',$(el).find('img.aaa:last').height()+60);
          $('img.classy').fadeIn();
```

It's embedded to click event. When I run it and click the area, img.classy FIRSTLY changes it's position, then on new position it fades out and fades in. I want obviously to make it that way: fade out -> change position when invisible -> fadein on new position. how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until the fadeOut is complete. I added a callback function for you.

```
$('img.classy').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).css('top',$(el).find('img.aaa:last').height()+60);
    $('img.classy').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! 
As yo u can see i'm positioning my image manually, maybe do you know how to position my image to appear under the specified image, exactly under it's right corner?

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
$('img.classy').fadeOut(function() {
    $('img.classy').css('top',$(el).find('img.aaa:last').height()+60);
    $('img.classy').fadeIn();
});
```

Because `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` are asynchronous functions, the script continues to run, those causing your `img` to change its position immediately.

Answer (score 0):

this will clone the img, remove it and append it anothor wrapper:

```
   .aaa {position: relative}
   .classy {position: absolute; right:0; top:0}

    $('img.classy').fadeOut(
      cloned = $(this).clone(true);
      $(this).remove();
      $("img.aaa:last").append(cloned);
      $(".classy").fadeIn();
    );
```